# How to create activity indicator for collection view .see detail in post

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

i have one collection view. i tried with storyboard but not able to add. Now how to create a uiactivity indicator with some 2.0 sec delay.and that should be in middle centre of my collection view using programatically

Any can help me.I am new to ios. i have tried but no animation to see.Please help me out.

1. need activity indicator at middle when my view loads
2. should start animating for 2.0 sec, after that its should hide.Whenever my collection view screen shows up that indicator should start animating for 2.0 sec and should hide

i have tried this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   //self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;


    programaticActivityIndicatorView_ = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [self.programaticActivityIndicatorView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self.programaticActivityIndicatorView setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [self.programaticActivityIndicatorView setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 239)];


    [self performSelector:@selector(methodsq) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

    [self.view addSubview:self.programaticActivityIndicatorView];



}

-(void)methodsq {

    [programaticActivityIndicatorView_ startAnimating];


}
```

But i continuously animating , but i need to animate only for 3.0 sec alone after that it should hide
Thanks !

Comment: you should put here what you achieve till now so we can help you to solve your problems

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into some of the outstanding activity indicator libraries such as https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD

Comment: for view controller i used via storyboard.But when i ad activity indicator for collection view its fill with whole screen.But i dont know how to create it programatically to set that middle and start & stop indicator

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
```

Synthesize it

```
@synthesize indicator;
```

Create Process

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake((rect.size.width-50)/2, (rect.size.height-50)/2, 50, 50);
self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
```

Start process

```
[self.indicator performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Hide when you want

```
[self.indicator performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: that start and hide is where i have to do that......in my view did load method ??--- if i start my animating then inside this method `-(void) startAnimating {  }  -- what i will do inside this method

Comment: No need to implement `startAnimating()` method. This is built in method of `UIActivityIndiactor` class

Comment: Just put all code in `viewDidLoad()`, except declaration and synthesise